# Plotting Matplotlib Histogram of one pandas dataframe column with average of another represented by a dot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

Basically have a pandas dataframe that looks like :

```
d = {'Percentage' : [8,20,24,27, 58], 'Assets' : [10,12,53,32,11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to create a histogram of the Percentage column with the frequency a percentage falls with in bin, which I did with :

```
bins = [0,25,50,75,100]

a = sns.FacetGrid(df)

a = a.map(plt.hist, "Percentage", bins=bins)
```

But now I want to overlay a dot representing the average assets of the bin in the histogram which I can't do.

I know I can group the assets column by the bin their respective percentage falls under and then calculate the mean and overlay another plot, but I feel like their must be another way.

EDIT: Clarification by what I meant by bins

Comment: Seems like you actually want a bar plot. Are you sure you want a histogram?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. I just want a count of percentages in each bin (that's where the histogram idea came up) and then something to represent the average assets of each of bin.

Comment: What are the bins you are referring to?

Comment: Sorry should've made the original post more clear. I'll edit it. But I mean counting the number of values in the Percentage column between 0-24,25-49, etc. Then find the average assets of each group.

Answer (score 0):

A histogram would work here, but I think it's easier to calculate it yourself and use a bar graph--given that you have to deal with `Assets` as well.

The idea is that you need to determine which bin each data point belongs. Then you can group by bin and average to calculate your average `Assets`. This is handled fairly well by seaborn actually:

```
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['Percentage'], bins=bins)
df['count'] = 1

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
sns.barplot(data=df, x='bins', y='count', estimator=np.sum, ax=ax1)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.pointplot(data=df, x='bins', y='Assets', color='m', join=False, ci=None, ax=ax2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is exactly what I was looking for.